# .htaccess fake subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, subdirectory

So I have this code creating a "fake directory"

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ?username=$1
```

But now I want a fake subdirectory with it, e.g.

> profile/johnsmith/photos

and that will Rewrite to

> ?username=johnsmith&tab=photos

**EDIT**

I have tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ?username=$1&tab=$2
```

Comment: ... and so, ? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$ ?username=$1&tab=$3
```